# Implementing AMP on existing responsive website

Tags: amp-html

I am a newbee to AMP. I have a responsive website and I need to implement AMP on its home page. Is it possible to make it AMP compitable without effecting Desktop view? Or I need to rewrite separate code for AMP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use @media to differentiate mobile and desktop views.

From [Create responsive AMP pages](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/responsive_design):

> In responsive design, you can use CSS `@media` queries to tailor the styling of your web page for various screen dimensions without having to alter the content of the page. In AMP, you can continue to use those same CSS `@media` queries. Additionally, for finer control over an AMP element, you can specify the `media` attribute on the element. This is particularly useful when you need to either show or hide an element based on a media query. See the [Changing the art direction of an image](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/responsive_design#changing-the-art-direction-of-an-image) section for an example that uses the `media` attribute.

For javascripts,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (screen.width < 980) { 

    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="amp mobile.js"></script>');  
 } else{
     import other js
 }

</script>
```

Comment: How about jQuery and customer JS? Can we have it for Desktop view?

Comment: But AMP doesn't allow custom JS. How would above code will get cached by Google ?

Comment: how about having a new page only for amp by adding this in actual desktop version homepage?
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.example.com/blog-post/amp/">

Comment: more about it here https://searchengineland.com/get-started-accelerated-mobile-pages-amp-240688

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you "upgrade" your desktop site to be AMP (remove Javascript and use AMP components).

You would typically create a separate AMP page (it can easily be responsive as AMP has good support for that), and include that AMP page using a link as:

```
<link rel=amphtml ....>
```

See https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/discovery for details.